# In JavaScript HOWTO pass uninstantiated object to constructor call of different class, which is instantiated later in the timeline?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, instantiation

During instantiating an object **VarA** of **ClassA** I pass in a variable **VarB** which acts as a placeholder for an object of **ClassB**. After **VarA** is instantiated; somewhere later in the pipeline I assign newly instantiated object of ClassB TO **VarB**.

In **ClassA** I save reference to **VarB** & then use this to do any work.

The problem I am facing is that when I try to use any method on **VarA** that depends upon **VarB**, I get errors saying VarB is undefined. This confuses me because before I use these methods I make sure that VarB is properly instantiated. And since I am saving the reference to VarB, it should be pointing to the corect object, right?

**UPDATE** - Code sample as requested.

```
var varA, varB;

// Code

varA = new ClassA({
     varB: varB
});

// Code

varB = new ClassB({
   attributeB: "SOME_VALUE",
});

// Class Definition for ClassA which uses varB

var ClassA = Class.extend({

    varB: {},

    init: function(settings) {
        this.varB = settings.varB;
    },

    dummyMethod: function() {

       // Do Something with varB.attributeB

    }

});
```

Not sure if this matters but I am using [John Resig's Class Extend Util for Simple JavaScript Inheritance.](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) as the base class of all my Classes.

Comment: A little minimal test-case goes a *long* way. The best way is generally to "fix the design", but without said minimal test-case it's hard to come up with a concrete solution. (Also, there are no classes, only objects viewed with a narrowed vision :-)

Comment: You should post the code itself for us to see; something sounds slightly suspicious about your description, and seeing the actual code would let me check to see if I'm right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got something like this:

```
var VarB = null, VarA = new ClassA(VarB);
```

and then later, when you're ready, you do this:

```
VarB = new ClassB();
```

then what that "VarA" object is holding onto is the "null" value you passed in, and you've *changed* the value of "VarB" to something else. There's no way to do what you describe, at least not exactly.  JavaScript is strictly **pass by value**, which means that when you make a function call, you're passing the **value** of the argument expression to the function. Inside the "ClassA" constructor, the fact that the "null" happened to come from a variable in the calling scope called "VarB" is completely hidden; it's just a "null".

Now, what you *can* do is this:

```
var VarB = { actualB: null }, VarA = new ClassA(VarB);
```

and then later:

```
VarB.actualB = new ClassB();
```

In that case, you would **not** be changing the value of "VarB"; you'd be changing the value of a property of the object referenced by "VarB".  If the "ClassA" code were written to stash that parameter and refer to its "actualB" property, then it would work.

Comment: I think this is a good idea. I will try it out and report back my results. My alternative was to create a setter method in ClassA specifically for setting value of varB. But this will mean that I am creating a not so clear dependency of always using the setter method before I can ever use any other methods in ClassA.

Comment: Actually, if I may, which idea will be cleaner? using a dummy VarB initially as suggested above or using a setter method as I described here?

Comment: Well, it kind-of depends on your application, I guess. There's not really anything wrong with either way, though if you think about it you've already got a dependency this way ...